# Cursor following frame in wxpython

Tags: timer, cursor, wxpython

I have a frame that follows the cursor, the code does work but the frame isn't at the exact speed of the cursor and it keeps flashing, could please help me?

```
import wx

class aaa (wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'aaa',size=(200,200),style = wx.NO_BORDER)
        panel=wx.Panel(self, id, pos = (0,0),size = (200,200))
        self.on_timer()

    def on_timer(self):
        wx.CallLater(0, self.on_timer)
        cursor = self.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
        self.SetPosition((cursor[0],cursor[1]))
```

Comment: Please delete your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220974/making-a-cursor-with-wxpython) (duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in you class `aaa`:

```
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    ...
    # remove self.on_timer()
    ...
    self.tmr = wx.Timer(self, id=wx.NewId())
    self.tmr.Start(100, wx.TIMER_CONTINUOUS)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer_evt)

def on_timer_evt(self, evt):
    mouse = wx.GetMousePosition()
    _, _, w, h = self.GetRect()
    self.SetPosition((mouse[0] - w/2, mouse[1] - h/2))
```

Close the window by pressing Alt-F4. Things can be sped up by lowering the interval between timer shots (`100` miliseconds in that case).

However, this cursor-following-functionality is somehow pointless to me because you will not be able to interact with something else in the wx GUI.